# Как после отрабатывания одного скрипта, отключить другой

Tags: html, jquery, css

```
//Первый скрипт. После отрабатывания данного скрипта, должен отключиться второй

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cross').click(function(){
        $('.block').addClass('none')
        $('.nav').addClass('dilspay')
        $('.blocked').addClass('blocka')
    });
});

//Второй скрипт

$(document).ready(function() {
    var block = 150; 
    var nav = $('#nav');
    nav.css({'position' : 'fixed', 'top' : block + 'px'});

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(top < block){
            nav.css({'top': block - top +'px'});
        } else {
            nav.css({'top': '0'});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: А что значит "отключиться" ? Вернуть состояние DOM к моменту своего не запуска? Или должен отключится обработчик скролла? или что? И отрабатывание - это навешивание обработчика нажатия, или после выполнения обработчика нажатия?

Comment: должен отключится обработчик скролла

Comment: На заметку, не обязательно заворачивать слушатели в отдельные `$(document).ready(function() {});`, достаточно перечислить все слушатели в одной функции `ready`

Answer (score 2):

> должен отключится обработчик скролла

Вам нужно снять с window обработчик скролла, в `jquery` это делается с помощью `off` (http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Упрощённый пример:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cross').click(function(){
        console.log('off');

        $(window).off('scroll', onScroll);
    });

    var onScroll = function() {
      console.log('scroll');
    };
    $(window).on('scroll', onScroll);
});
```

`.off()` можно вызвать только с одним параметром `scroll`, это отключит все обработчики скролла.